# How to query Python event loop monotonic clock resolution

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Currently the asyncio event loop simply calls `time.monotonic()`, so we can easily query the resolution with `time.get_clock_info('monotonic').resolution`, but in case the asyncio implementation changes do we have a public API available for querying that new monotonic clock's resolution (i.e., can we query the resolution of `asyncio.get_event_loop().time()`)?

Comment: We would need to predict the future to tell what exact API a possible new implementation has, wouldn't we?

Comment: @KlausD. Not necessarily. I'm hoping that somewhere in the docs is an asyncio counterpart to `get_clock_info` which any new implementation would need to adhere to and which I haven't been able to find.

Comment: What is the purpose of querying the resolution? Even if you found out the resolution of the timer, you still couldn't rely on the resolution of the select/poll primitive used by the event loop, which is what ultimately drives the resolution of `call_later`, `call_at`, `asyncio.sleep`, etc.

Comment: @user4815162342 The use case I had in mind is that in the face of remote rate-limiting you might want to self-limit to avoid any consequences of exceeding `n` calls in a window of `t` seconds (as interpreted by a remote monotonic clock). An optimal throughput algorithm basically looks like "wait until some simple function of a lot of variables, including an upper bound on local clock resolution, then dispatch the next event." If the loop delays events further then that's just overhead which doesn't render the results incorrect (just less efficient, but we knew that when we decided on asyncio).

Comment: @user4815162342 In some environments for some parameters though, a 15.6ms resolution (looking at you Windows) can significantly reduce optimal throughput. I basically don't care about the difference between 1ns, 0.1ns, etc... in the timer resolution (asycio overhead always eats those gains), but the difference between 15.6ms and 1ns can be impactful.

Comment: FWIW: seems undocumented, but is used internally: `asyncio.get_event_loop()._clock_resolution` (source file: `asyncio/base_events.py`; function `BaseEventLoop.__init__`). And I guess the probability of having two different monotonic clocks is quite close to zero.

Comment: @VpfB Excellent! If a function is used internally and never exposed then that strongly indicates the thing I want doesn't quite exist while also allowing for a much nicer default behavior than what I had before (try to grab `_clock_resolution` if it exists, falling back to `get_clock_info` and issuing a warning otherwise). If you wanted to turn that into an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: @HansMusgrave I'm glad I could help. I don't think my short comment is worth extra points. I will post it as an regular answer when the bounty expires. Is that OK?

Comment: Certainly, whatever you're comfortable with. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asyncio source in the standard library is part of a Python installation.

In the `asyncio/base_events.py` file there is an event loop base class. In its initialization function it saves the clock resolution for its internal use.

```
self._clock_resolution = time.get_clock_info('monotonic').resolution
```

and the mentioned usage is:

```
    # Handle 'later' callbacks that are ready.
    end_time = self.time() + self._clock_resolution
    while self._scheduled:
        handle = self._scheduled[0]
        if handle._when >= end_time:
            break
```

I could not find other uses in the 3.9.1 asyncio code.

The conclusion is that with a high probability there is no public API, but the clock resolution value can be obtained from the mentioned private attribute belonging to the event loop. As always, there is no guarantee when dealing with an undocumented private data.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be most practical to raise an Exception (perhaps with further direction) if there is insufficient accuracy.

```py
import time
if time.get_clock_info('monotonic').resolution > accuracy_limit:
    raise OSError("monotonic timer is insufficiently accurate")
```

EDIT: ah, not quite; re-reading, the question is perhaps better *how to detect if the asyncio implementation is not backed by `time.monotonic()`*?

However, I suggest that such an implementation is unlikely as it seems needlessly bad (ie. it would be some fraction of a different monotonic clock than is provided to Python?..), and also that systems *must* provide a monotonic clock (detecting if the timer is really monotonic is left as an exercise to the reader)

Comment: "re-reading, the question is perhaps better how to detect if the asyncio implementation is not backed by time.monotonic()?" >> Not really. Detection is better than nothing, but by itself it can't fully replicate the functionality I'd like.

Comment: hmm .. I don't think I fully understand then. Specifically, detecting the backing _may_ be an easier task or not, but if the backing really _can be assumed_ (which I suspect, though am not certain it can), then your knowledge of how to detect accuracy of the timer is sufficient to prove the accuracy of the asyncio implementation.

Comment: I already have an implementation of my desired algorithm assuming the backing doesn't change; it just feels dirty to rely on an implementation detail like that, so I'm curious if there might be an additional asyncio-specific API for clock resolution (note that _any_ resolution is fine; I simply have to change my behavior based on the available resolution -- the tighter the worst-case resolution the tighter my best-case performance guarantees can be for an algorithm built on asyncio).

Comment: In particular, that's why detection doesn't quite suffice -- if I can detect that `time.monotonic` isn't being called then I still can't assume anything about the resolution (though on modern machines I might optimistically assume it's at least 16ms), and the resolution is the only clock parameter I really care about.